# IOS NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 in Spring rest service oauth

Tags: ios, spring, rest, oauth

I have a Spring security rest service, and it´s secured by oauth2 and it works fine, but when i try to access in IOS I have this error:

```
Error happened = Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)"
```

My code is:

```
NSString *post = @"http://localhost:8080/oauth/token";

NSString *params =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"password=%@&username=%@&grant_type=password&scope=read&client_secret=123456&client_id=clientapp",@"1234",@"user"];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:post];

     NSData * postData = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:30.0f];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
       [urlRequest setHTTPBody: postData];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
     [urlRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;


NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection
 sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
 queue:queue
 completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                     NSData *data,
                     NSError *error) {
     ... }]
```

Thanks!

Comment: -1012 NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication, can you increase the timeout to 60s ?

Comment: I´ve tried to change the timeout and it never works.

Comment: same error message ?

Comment: I get the same error. in curl I need to use "-vu clientapp:123456"

Comment: can you try this from google chrome's advanced rest plugin and see whether it works properly ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHL_eUAHHLI

Comment: I solved the problem. I needed to add basic authentication in Base64 encode. Thanks for your help @thndrkiss.